# Angular app to acknowledge where the user is coming from

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have 3 different angular applications with 3 different url.

1. Login app
2. Launcher app
3. Content app
   User need to access from
   login > launcher > content.
   And if they log out would be
   Content > launcher > login

Since browser won't share the history detail to the angular app.
Is there a good way to let the 2. Launcher app acknowledge the user is coming from 1. Login app but not 3. Content app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by sending params in the url
Example if you coming from login your link should be
https://www.example.com/home?origin=login
And by this you can know if you came from login or from other web